# Minimizing the magnitude of the sum of a vector of complex numbers with an integer constraint

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, integer-partitions, integer-programming, set-partition

Let $h_{1}, ..., h_{N} \in \mathbb{C} $

Consider minimizing the function below:

$ \min \left| \sum\limits_{i=1}^N h_{i} x_{i} \right| $

with the constraints $x_{i}^2 = 1$
i.e., $x_{i}$ can only take on the values $1$ or $-1$.

Effectively, I am trying to partition the complex elements into $2$ sets such that the sum of the complex numbers in both respective sets are close to equal to each other. Then, the difference between the sum of the 2 sets of complex numbers will be as close to $0$ as possible.

This problem can be solved using a Semi-Definite Programming (SDP) relaxation approach or using a Non-Linear Programming (NLP) approach but **I am looking for a more efficient dynamic program or integer program solution which would require less than $2^n$ searches to find the optimal solution.**

**I have looked into the Number Partitioning Problem (Npp) ([PDF](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0310317)) and wanted to know if there was a similar approach for a set of complex numbers rather than a set of real numbers.**

Comment: It is a mixed-integer SOCP or QP. Not sure how efficient it will be though, depends on the solver.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I am not sure how I can formulate it as a mixed-integer SOCP, could you please clarify that?

Comment: Say $x_i=2z_i-1$ where $z_i$ are binary, then let $u=\sum h_ix_i$ and treating $u$ as living in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the objective is to minimize $\|u\|_2$.